# Best practices on Folder permissions

Tags: document-library, permissions, folder

When migrating a fileshare to SharePoint there is a tendency to copy the filestructure one-on-one to a library, and to maintain a permission setup based on folders.
Sometimes I read articles that is not best practices to structure permissions by folders, but that permissions should be set in sites and libraries. But then the disadvantages are not explained.
I know the fundamentals on setting permissions in sharepoint groups populated with securitygroups for Sites and libraries, but I find it hard to grasp the pro's and cons on using folders instead. For one thing, it is also possible to grant permissions to a group for a folder.
There must be strong arguments to change a way of working that is familiar for a organisation.
I wonder if any of you guys, would know these arguments, or else, don't mind a folder permission structure at all.

Comment: One argument against it is that item and folder level permissions are supposidly slow. Another is that it is often  not clear to end users who has access to what.

Comment: Dank je wel  JJT